# Safari Date Picker Clearing the value

Tags: javascript, html, safari

I am trying to use the safari date picker with a empty value, but it seems that whatever I add the there is a date shown in the control

```
<input type="date" />
```

displays a date input correctly, but shows todays date (albeit greyed out) but still shown in the control, what I would like todo is show the dd/MM/yyyy placeholder in the same way that chrome and FF do..

I hope this is clear, and thanks in advance,

M